# 'Control reaches end of non-void function' in C

Tags: c, user-input, fgets, fputs

I am trying to read the user's input. When I compile the program I get the message, 'control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}'.

```
char *read_line(char *buf, size_t sz) {
    while(fgets(buf, sz, stdin)) {
        fputs(buf, stdout);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *buf;

    read_line(buf, 1024);
}
```

I want the program to take the user's input, press enter, and have their input printed back out to them. I gotta do it using the methods I have used (it's part of some homework).

I don't fully know what is going on under the hood of C, so it is just causes some many problems like this :).

Comment: You never return anything from `read_line`. Do you really want it to be `char*`, or do you want it to return nothing and be `void`?

Comment: `buf` isn't pointing to anything.  You probably want an array instead of a pointer.

Comment: Also, `main()` is defined to be `int` but it's not returning anything either; best to add `return 0;` (or other suitable error code) at the end of that function.

Comment: In the my problem sheet, the method's type and arguments are given to us in the way it is in my code - I just gotta work around that. I am pretty confused about it because I am pretty new to C.

Comment: @SteveFriedl `main` is special in that it returns 0 by default.

Comment: `#define MAXC 1024` then in `main(...)` Declare `char buf[MAXC];` and call `read_line (buf, MAXC);` Add `return buf;` at the end of `read_line {...}`

Comment: @SteveFriedl `main` is the one function that will default `return 0` (C99 and on).

Comment: @interjay return can be omitted in C99 or C11, but technically it can't be omitted in older standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the function has undefined behavior because it uses an unitialized pointer.

And the function shall have a return statement if its return type is not void.

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_line( char *buf, size_t sz ) 
{
    while( fgets(buf, sz, stdin) && buf[0] != '\n' ) 
    {
        fputs(buf, stdout);
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 1024 };
    char buf[N];

    read_line( buf, N );
}
```

Or something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * read_line( char *buf, size_t sz ) 
{
    if  ( fgets(buf, sz, stdin) && buf[0] != '\n' ) 
    {
        return buf;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 1024 };
    char buf[N];

    char *p = read_line( buf, N );\

    if ( p != NULL ) fputs( p, stdout );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this but my homework sheet wants us to use 'char' rather than 'void' for the method.

Comment: @JakeJackson It does not make sense taking into account what you wrote relative to the assignment.

Comment: The C standard does not require a function to have a `return` statement even if it has a non-void return type, and reaching the end of a function with non-void return type does not, by itself, have undefined behavior.

Answer (score -2):

```
char *read_line(char *buf, size_t sz) {
    while(fgets(buf, sz, stdin)) {
        fputs(buf, stdout);
    }
     return buf;
}
```

Comment: this compiles but when I enter something, such as 'name', it it just says, 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

Comment: @JakeJackson That's because of the *undefined behavior* your code exhibits due to stuffing data into memory targeted by an indeterminate pointer in `main`, passed to `read_line`. It is also an entirely different problem than the question you posted. This answer is correct for what you asked (why is that warning being emitted), though it could certainly do a better job of explaining what is fixed, and why. Code-only answers are usually pretty lousy.

Comment: For such a beginner question, maybe you can add an explanation instead of a code dump.